# IBM Cloud: Access Cloud Foundry from app using API vs CLI?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I need to create a Node.js program which needs to run cf commands like `cf a`, `cf cs` etc.
While searching the web I found this two repos which don't seem official and no longer maintained anymore:

https://github.com/prosociallearnEU/cf-nodejs-client

https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/cf-nodejs-client

My question is, should I use those libraries or I can use a **child process** to call the cf cli commands (assume that the bin is in the env), what is preferred way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do NOT use the Cloud Foundry command line interface (CLI) for interacting with Cloud Foundry from an app. There are well-documented Cloud Foundry APIs for that. The CLI is just a wrapper around those API functions.

The [Cloud Foundry API endpoints for IBM Cloud](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry-public?topic=cloud-foundry-public-endpoints) are documented and available for use.

Comment: Thanks, is there any library ? or just run rest  call ?

Comment: I would use REST calls, but you can check here: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/capi/client-libraries.html It includes the Node.ls package you found earlier. It is not supported and may be outdated

Comment: thanks, 1+ , I just want to deep understand it, what are the cons of using the child process and run the cli ?assume that the env have the cli... any problem that you think that I can face in the future?

Comment: Not sure what you want to accomplish. Using the API you are independent of any operating system env. It is the recommended way for your type of problem. Please mark answered and upvote.